# Cloudinary $.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag response object not accessible

Tags: jquery, json, cloudinary

I have been using Cloudinary to upload images via their unsigned API. But a lot of the response text is inaccessible. I primarily need the file addition attached to the uploaded image name i.e.

> myImage_xJyk.jpg.

I tried reparsing the json, looping and trying to access the object keys. How can I get the response data from an unsigned upload.

```
$('.upload_form').append($.cloudinary.unsigned_upload_tag("abcdefg", {
        cloud_name: 'sample',
        api_key: '12345678910'
    },{
        multiple: true,
    })).bind('cloudinaryprogress', function(e, data) { 
        console.log(data.result.public_id);
    });
```

Comment: The example project provided here (https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_php/tree/master/samples/PhotoAlbum) is working perfectly. Please refer it.

Comment: None of those show how to get the public_id inside the JS version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cloudinaryprogress` only is relevant to the process of the upload itself, e.g., for indication of the upload progress. It doesn't know the public ID of the uploaded image yet. You'll need to bind to the `cloudinarydone` event instead to get the public ID of the upload image.

Comment: That makes sense, I will try this out tonight when I get home  and if it works out I'll be sure to accept the answer.

Comment: You wouldn't happen to have any insight on this question would you?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40063115/meteor-lepozepo-cloudinary-generate-signature