# Meteor Lepozepo Cloudinary Generate Signature

Tags: javascript, node.js, meteor, cloudinary

I am trying to upload an image in Meteor with the https://github.com/Lepozepo/cloudinary package. But I am not quite sure how to generate a url. Without it, I get a 401 error.

**Server**

```
Cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: 'sample',
    api_key: '1234567890',
    api_secret: '1AbCDEE789101010'
});

Cloudinary.rules.signature = function() {
  return this.userId;
};
```

**Client**

```
$.cloudinary.config({
cloud_name: 'sample',
api_key: '1234567891234567'
```

});

```
'change #image-upload' (event) {
    let files;
    files = event.currentTarget.files;
    return Cloudinary.upload(files, {
        cloud_name: 'sample',
        api_key: '1234567891234567'
    }, function(err, res) {
        console.log("Upload Error: " + err);
        return console.log("Upload Result: " + res);
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. I had this incorrect cloud name.  The above code should work as long as all your credentials are correct.